# How can I break a paragraph after every time a certain character shows up?

Tags: java, split, line-breaks

For example, in this block:

first line of the paragraph&second sentence, should end up on the second line&third part, should end up on third line

I want the output to have each sentence start on a new line, so essentially breaking the paragraph after ever ampersand.

How can I achieve this in java?

Comment: What have you tried so far? It's important to remember StackOverflow is not a code-writing service. We're happy to help, but we're not here to do everything for you. Think about the problem you've presented: you have a *string* and you want to *replace* each ampersand with a newline. Now think about where in the Java documentation you might find a solution to that problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your paragraph follows the same ending line pattern, you can easily use String split() method which will return an array of strings(your lines). Very powerful and easy to use. Here is a basic example:

```
String[] lines = "Peter;James;Thomas".split(";");
```